# What is the compiler rank in argument type conversion if the parameters differ?

Tags: c++, terminology, overload-resolution

I am wondering about the `rank` during overload resolution.

I am reading through *C++ Primer Fifth Edition*. On page 245 they state the following:

> 6.6.1 Argument Type Conversions
>
> 1. An exact match. An exact match happens when:
>
>    - The argument and parameter types are identical.
>    - The argument is converted from an array or function type to the corresponding pointer type.
>    - A top-level const is added to or discarded from the argument.
> 2. Match through a const conversion.
> 3. Match through a promotion.
> 4. Match through an arithmetic or pointer conversion.
> 5. Match through a class-type conversion.

This makes sense to me. In the exercises to the section (6.52) the ask the following:

Given the following declarations,

```
void manip(int, int);
double dobj;
```

what is the rank of each conversion in the following calls?

```
(a) manip('a', 'z');    (b) manip(55.4, dobj);
```

This seemed pretty straightforward. I figured this is `integral promotion` on both parameters.. So the rank is therefore **3**.

When trying to figure out (b), I come to the same conclusion.

Now this is all well and fine if the parameters are from the same type.
But what about this?

```
void manip(double, const int& x) {

}
```

When I call the function like this: `manip(2, 1);`
What is the `common` consensus for the rank in this circumstance?

There is a `match through a const conversion (2)` as well as a `match through a promotion (3)`. So is the rank **2.5** then? This doesn't seem so obvious to me.
I'm only interested in the terminological answer here. I know this is not really relevant by any means but I'm still interested. Do I misunderstand `rank` here?

On this [github page](https://github.com/adobrich/CppPrimer/tree/master/Chapter_06) they didn't argue with numbers either. What is the rank then in the common sense? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There are no mean/whole rank. Rank is done **by parameter**. overload resolution takes the overload which has less or equal rank for each of its parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah okay. But with more than one parameter. Does the compiler compare each and every one of them separately? It does have to do some arithmetic to keep track of the ranks then to give me the best overloaded function back doesn't it?

Comment: Is there even a number stored for the rank in the first place? I might be misunderstanding how this works entirely.

Comment: Assuming `foo(int, int, double)`/`foo(double, double, int)`, `foo(4.2, 4.2, 4.2)` would give respectively `(3, 3, 1)` and `(1, 1, 3)`. neither is best for each argument, so ambiguous call.

Comment: Compiler doesn't have to store numbers, it might do as it wants if it behaves as-if it uses the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seemed pretty straightforward. I figured this is integral promotion on both parameters.. So the rank is therefore 3.

There are no mean/whole rank. Rank is done **by parameter**.

So for both `(a)` and `(b)` each of the 2 parameters are integral promotion.
You might note `(3, 3)` not `3`.

So in case of `(3, 2)`, it is not `2.5` but `(3, 2)`

Overload resolution takes the overload which has less or equal rank for each of its parameter.

so

- `(1, 1, 2)` would be better than `(1, 2, 3)`
- `(1, 1, 3)` is not better than `(3, 3, 1)` (which is not better either). Here call would be ambiguous (if no other best overload).

Answer (score 0):

In the context of programming languages, when passing arguments to a function or method, the compiler uses a rank-based system to determine the most appropriate conversion of argument types when the parameters differ. The compiler first checks for an exact match, then for a match with promotions (e.g., converting int to float). If no exact or promotable match is found, it looks for standard conversions (e.g., converting int to double). If none of these are applicable, the compiler will consider user-defined conversions. If no match is found, it will raise a type mismatch error, indicating that the function cannot be called with the provided arguments.

Comment: Well this doesn't really answer my question. I was mainly wondering about what the compiler does internally. Does the compiler use arithmetic to figure the rank out? Is the rank attached to a number?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question; they already said they understand the different ranks, just not how they are applied